# Playframework 2.x - prevent assets caching

Tags: java, scala, caching, cache-control, playframework-2.0

I'm using playframework v2 and I have my sitemap files being re-created once a day by an external process. They're all in the assets folder/sitemap

How do I force playframework to return the file directly from disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the file (from disk or WS) and render the content in a classic Action, then set the cache with an annotation :

```
@Cached(key="sitemap", duration=86400)
public static Result index() {
  // ... set sitemap variable from your file
  return ok(siteMap);
}
```

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaCache

Or you can achieve the same behavior with a job.

Answer (score 1):

put it in the /public folder.. resources from there are not intercepted/processed by any controller, etc.

so if you put your file into the folder /public/sitemaps/sitemap.xml it will be available as yoursite.com/public/sitemaps/sitemap.xml

Comment: Sorry I may have mislead you. The files are already in the public folder. But that public folder is accessible at site.com/assets/* If play isn't processing them then something's a miss because they're cached. The new version of the file is given if I stop the process and restart